# What function can I use to filter my array of objects by (potentially) multiple criteria?

Tags: php

### Problem

Based on user-inputted fields (`'title'`, `'note'`, `'due-date'`, `'priority'`, & `'course'`), I am filtering the `$tasks` array which holds `Task` objects. Based on the user-inputted field(s) (the user can either fill out 1 field or multiple), `getSearchResults()` is suppose to filter `$tasks` and return an array of `Task` objects (i.e. `$filtered_tasks`) that match all those search criteria (so it's an AND kind of search).

However, I'm getting the error `'Undefined variable: value'` because I'm using the variable `$value` for the function in `array_filter()`. My question is, how do I make it so I can use the variable `$value` in the `array_filter()`? Or what other function can I use to filter my array of `Task` objects by certain criteria?

### Code

```
function getSearchResults($tasks){
$search_fields = getSearchFields();
$filtered_tasks = $tasks;
foreach($search_fields as $field => $value){
    //Filter array based on field
    if($field === 'title'){
        $filtered_tasks = array_filter($filtered_tasks,     function($obj) {
            return ($obj->title === $value);
        });
    }
    if($field === 'note'){
        $filtered_tasks = array_filter($filtered_tasks,     function($obj) {
            return ($obj->note === $value);
        });
    }
    if($field === 'due-date'){
        $filtered_tasks = array_filter($filtered_tasks,     function($obj) {
            return ($obj->due_date === $value);
        });   
    }
    if($field === 'priority'){
        $filtered_tasks = array_filter($filtered_tasks,     function($obj) {
            return ($obj->priority === $value);
        });    
    }
    if($field === 'course'){
        $filtered_tasks = array_filter($filtered_tasks,     function($obj) {
            return ($obj->course === $value);
        });
    }
}

return $filtered_tasks;
}

function getSearchFields(){
$search_fields = array();
if(!empty($_POST['title'])){
    $search_fields['title'] = $_POST['title'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['note'])){
    $search_fields['note'] = $_POST['note'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['due-date'])){
    $search_fields['due-date'] = $_POST['due-date'];
}
if($_POST['priority'] !== ''){
    $search_fields['priority'] = $_POST['priority'];
}
if($_POST['course']!==''){
    $search_fields['course'] = $_POST['course'];
}

return $search_fields;
}

class Task{
public $title;
public $due_date;
public $priority;
public $course;
public $note;

function __construct($title, $due_date, $priority, $course, $note) {
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->due_date = $due_date;
    $this->priority = $priority;
    $this->course = $course;
    $this->note = $note;
}

public function is_empty(){
    return ($this->title === '' || $this->due_date === '' || $this->priority === '' || $this->course ==='' || $this->note ==='');
}
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also pass `$field` to your anonymous function and change this line: `return ($obj->note === $value);` to: `return ($obj->$field === $value);` saving some code.